# Off the list or out of the list

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Let's say a teacher in a class of 50 students, is finding out who cheated on an exam. And then the teacher said that you are **(excluded)**: edited to:**not on the list**

> Don't worry you are **off the list** who cheated on the exam. coz' I trust you.

Or

> Don't worry you are **out of the list** who cheated on the exam. coz' I trust you.

Which is more correct?

Comment: Regardless of which is *more* correct (I would say the former), the most natural sounding phrase in general is what you used when you asked the question: *Don't worry. You are **not on the list** (of those who cheated on the exam).*

Comment: Few teachers would write "coz" for "because"  But if they did I hope they would capitalise the first letter of the sentence, and put the apostrophe in the right place ’Coz I trust you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are excluded** is a strange thing for the teacher to say.

If the teacher has drawn up a list of cheats, either you are *on the list* or *not on the list*.

If you have not been included in the list, it's not the same thing as being excluded.

To say you have been excluded means that you have been prevented from being part of it - or joining it.

And because pupils cheated, the list didn't, you need to speak about: *...the list **of those** who cheated*.

So the teacher would need to inform you:

> Don't worry. You are not on (or **included in**) the list of those who cheated....

Comment: the original quote is very informal "coz' I trust you." I feel  "the list of cheaters" would match the tone of the sentence.

Comment: I know the phrase ''**not on the list''** but can I say ''**off the list**'' and **"out of the list**" to mean the same thing?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the question has been edited so much as to now make the answer here almost seem off topic.

Comment: I just re-structured my edit, ok now?, could you answer the question here on this comment thread

Comment: I think Ronald has answered the question.  You should say "you are not on the list" rather that "off" or "out of" the list.